# Mavensmate shortcut for Implementing/Overriding methods?

Tags: ide, mavensmate

The below example is for Java:

**TestInterface.Java**:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    public void methodOne();
}
```

In Eclipse for Java, If I want to implement methods of the Interface, it would show up all the methods from the Interface and then I can choose whichever I want.. Below screenshot.

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Is there any such thing for Apex, Without opening the interface and copying the method name..Any shortcut for this kind of scenario?

**Note:** 
Opened [an issue](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/504) for mavensmate project assuming it might not be happening already but just want to know from you guys, If you have any workaround or how do you do in these scenarios.

Comment: One of the mavensmate contributor responded to the issue on github and it is kind of a workaround but it works and saves time!